# Weird link parsing on home page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

The page that I'm developing seems to generate a ?i=1 on its home address brought by the theme that it uses, namely Hiero by aThemes. I understand that it had yet to be updated, but I would like to be guided on what should I look for in the theme itself and what should be done to prevent it from displaying the latter issue. And yes, it's not brought by the plugins. Nor had I even used any plugin yet.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that I had already tried to refresh my permalinks but still no dice.

EDIT 2:
Here's the .htaccess contents.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`
```

Comment: got to dashboard > settings > permalinks  and select postname and click on save and open the url in private tab

Comment: already done that, but still no dice. Forgot to mention it.

Comment: can you share your .htacess file code

Comment: Try temporarily switching the theme to see if it fixes the issue. If it is not, the problem might lie in .htaccess file and not in the theme.

Comment: checked .htaccess file, no abnormalities whatsoever, still the problem persists.

Comment: I've added the .htacess on the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found where the problem is; It's the hosting server itself, they use such parameters to block spam and bots.